# Google Map Street View capture is not working using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, screen-capture

I'm having problems capturing a screen shot of google maps street view with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) and [canvas2Image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image). Capturing a map works fine ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDB9P.jpg)), but [the screenshot of the Street View interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbUu8.jpg) turns out mostly black.

Code used:

```
$('#capture').click(function(){
    html2canvas($('#mapCanvas'), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var capture = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            return capture;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is only a workaround but apparently this issue was already reported in [github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1330) back in December 2017 and disabling Hardware Acceleration in chrome does the trick.

Comment: Thanks @evan for your reply, I found a better workaround to fix this
This how do I do that and this may help someone has the same issue:
I used the static street view of google map 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro
and save the image that I want, by passing the position (or pano), fov, pitch and heading to the google api and then saved the returned image
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Thanks again

Comment: Happy to hear! Thanks for your update and for sharing this with the community. :)